# Streaming with gstreamer to vlc using tcpserversink

Tags: tcp, gstreamer, vlc, rtp

I'm attempting to stream an h264 encoded video using gstreamer and tcp. The command is:

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600 ! x264enc key-int-max=12 !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink port=5000

gop size is set to 12, and configuration sent every second.  I can't receive this stream using vlc (neither on the same machine nor on other machine). The command on vlc is:

vlc rtp://localhost:5000

but nothing showed. Anyone can help ?
regards

Comment: gdppay is a non standards protocol which is intended to be decoded with gdpdepay. Again this is non-standard and nothing with properly decode it except with gdpdepay.

Answer (score 9):

wrap the stream up in some container like mpegts

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc key-int-max=12 byte-stream=true ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink port=8888 host=localhost
```

now in vlc using tcp://localhost:8888